# What is the proper object name for java?

Tags: java, object

I started learning object-oriented java 2 days ago. I am not an IT or ComSci student/graduate. I am just into learning new stuffs.

I read about the objects in java. So, I know that the syntax for creating an object is:

> MyObject object = new MyObject();

I kinda figured out that the object can be named anything else just like a java method. However, I do not get how to name the MyObject.

I have this simple code below:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class sample extends JFrame
{
     public static void main(String[] args) 
     {

        sample sample = new sample();

        sample.setVisible(true);
        sample.setSize(300, 200);
        sample.setTitle("Simple");
     }
}
```

The code above shows that i have the object

> sample sample = new sample();

and it works fine.  If i change it to

> JFrame sample = new JFrame();

it still does work fine. If i deleted **extends JFrame** and uses the same object, it will still work. Without the **extends JFrame** and i use the object **sample sample = new sample();** then it wont work.
Lastly, this is what really confuse me. If i have the **extends JFrame** and i change the object into **Employee sample = new Employee();** then it will create an error. It says "Cannot find symbol".

Is there a proper object naming for objects and where should i rely on naming objects?

Comment: "it still does work fine." That's because all the methods you call on `sample` (btw, use naming conventions so your class is called `Sample`) are methods inherited from `JFrame`.

Comment: I suggest you to check the following document, it is official Oracle Code convention guide https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: I think you need to google "Java inheritance".

Comment: I suggest you continue studying with a proper tutorial or book. As you advance through your studies, these things will become clear.

Comment: If you really want to learn Java, you'll find it much more effective to start with the official [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: And note: please also study java naming conventions. Class names go UpperCase, always. So you can distinguish them from variable names easily. "sample sample = new sample()" ... that creates only confusion!

Comment: Finally: the **name** of a variable very much depends on its purpose. Assume you have different colors, then you would rather go `Color red = new Color(whatever);` ... the point is: the **name** expresses the intent. The purpose of the thing that carries that name. Sometimes that could be the name of the class, but that creates a lot of redundancy, so not helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using `extends JFrame`, you can use the methods in the `JFrame` class - see Java docs on [inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

If you remove `extends JFrame`, you can't use `setVisible`, `setSize` or `setTitle` as they are then not methods anywhere you can access in the current state - they exist in the [`JFrame`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) class

Using `Employee sample = new Employee();` fails because it's looking for a class called `Employee` and trying to make an object of it in `sample` (which should be `Sample` by the way) by invoking the constructor but the `Employee` class doesn't exist in your code.

`sample sample = new sample();` works because that's the name of your class you're currently in, i.e. you're creating an instance of it.

Comment: So when naming objects, it should be then based on the class? I see. Thank you.

Comment: @NathanNiel In the easiest example you create an object like `<Class> <variable> = new <Class>` where `Class` is the class object you want an instance of, and `variable` is what you name said instance. `variable` can technically be whatever you choose to call it, but in reality they are usually just called the same as the `Class` except in lower case, i.e. `Class class = new Class();`